# html input is calling wrong action

Tags: html, submit-button, multiple-forms

I'm try to perform different actions in a login form with 2 button. The first is a logout button, and the second would perform email sending. See my code below:

**Code**

```
<form action="xxx/default_logout.php" method="post" id="login form">

    <!-- Logout button -->
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%">
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button-setting" value="Logout"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
       <input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.logout" />
       <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return; ?>" />
       <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token');
    </div>

    <!-- Mail button -->
    <div style="float: right; width: 66%">
       <div>
            <form action='xxxxx/mail.php' method="post"> 
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="buttonR-setting" value="Mail"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
                <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Problem**

It always jump to `logout.php` whether I click `logout` or `mail`, but I expected *logout* would goto `logout.php` while *mail* would goto `mail.php`.

**Question**

I want to know

(i) how to fix the code, noted that I want both `logout` & `mail` be the components of the form *and*

(ii) what is the mechanism between `submit` and `action`, how do they bind together.

Any help would be very much appreciative.

**Update**

So far, I've try to execute it by JavaScript. Unfortunately, It still doesn't work.

```
<form action='xxxxx/mail.php' method="post" id="mail_form"> 
<input type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" name="Submit" id="buttonR-setting" value="Mail"/>
</form>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById('mail_form').submit()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you assign same id `id="button-setting"` for both buttons?

Comment: for CSS styling

Comment: That happens because you have a form inside another, you will have to handle this with js

Comment: I've try to use `onClick()` and `getElementById`, and execute it by `.submit`. Sadly, It's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to your question, but you need to tell the form "don't do anything when I click submit", so then your JavaScript can execute.
So your form tags need this:

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

Then your `myFunction()` will execute without the page submitting the form, too.